Какой гайд по с# учить и как учить
у меня такая так сказать проблема, я учусь в колледже на программиста и делаю лабы по C# постоянно с ChatGPT, что-то я знаю какую-то теорию, но даже не базу, программу сам написать не смогу и вот мне это не нравится, хочу сам как-то разбираться и учить. Можете пожалуйста, кто действительно шарит в C# подсказать, как его учить, где можно его выучить (источники имеется ввиду) и какие гайлв смотреть на ютубе (авторов гайдов).

Чтобы что-то написать, надо знать, что должно получиться. Поверьте, вы даже предложение на русском языке написать не сможете, если не знаете, что писать. Ресурсов, видео, тренажёров полно. Было бы желание. Берите задачи и решайте.
